# Including a button at the bottom of all WordPress posts to link to set custom fields links

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I'd like to add a button that shows at the bottom of every WordPress post on my site. This button should link to a specific URL that is set using the Custom fields plugin and then chosen on each post when it's created.

I have managed to create the button to show at the bottom of each post, however, I'm not able to pull in the Custom fields setup I'd defined.

Here is the code I have but this currently links back to the post in which the button is displayed and not the URL which is set on the individual post.

```
function wpb_after_post_content( $content ) {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        $content .= '<a href="'.$franchise_profile_url.'" target="_blank" class="franchise-profile-btn">Contact Franchise &rarr;</a>';
    }
    return $content;
}

add_filter( "the_content", "wpb_after_post_content" );
```

I have this working currently on a certain post types by adding this code into the theme itself but it doesn't work on all the posts types I use and I'm not able to replicate this for other posts so this is why I'm trying to add this to the functions.php file to show after every post content instead.

```
<?php if( get_field('franchise_profile_url') ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_field('franchise_profile_url'); ?>" target="_blank" class="franchise-profile-btn">Contact Franchise &rarr;</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help with be greatly received as I've been racking my brains with this one for a while now.

Comment: Why are you not add this second part of code to single.php template file?

Comment: Do all your post types have the `franchise_profile_url` in them or just the custom post type the link is rendering on? Just by reading your question, my first guess would be they dont, since you are conditionally rendering the link based on that field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```php
function wpb_after_post_content($content){
if (is_single() && get_field('franchise_profile_url')) {
    $content .= '<a href="'.get_field('franchise_profile_url').'" target="_blank" class="franchise-profile-btn">Contact Franchise &rarr;</a>';
}
    return $content;
}
add_filter( "the_content", "wpb_after_post_content" );
```

That will show the link only on single posts and if the `franchise_profile_url` field exists.